# Can't import FlaskForm from Flask-WTF

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have an existing Flask application and am trying to add the Flask-Blogging extension to it. Adding the extension raises `ImportError: cannot import name FlaskForm` when `flask_blogging` tries `from flask_wtf import FlaskForm`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 11, in <module>
    blog_engine = BloggingEngine(app, sql_storage)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_blogging/engine.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.init_app(app, storage)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_blogging/engine.py", line 96, in init_app
    from .views import create_blueprint
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_blogging/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    from flask_blogging.forms import BlogEditor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_blogging/forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
ImportError: cannot import name FlaskForm
```

I am using Flask 0.11.1 and Flask-WTF 0.12.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have an old version of Flask-WTF installed, but Flask-Blogging expects a newer version. Upgrade Flask-WTF.

```
pip install -U Flask-WTF
```

[Flask-WTF renamed `Form` to `Flask-Form` in version 0.13, released September 29, 2016.](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/changelog.html#version-0-13)

Answer (score -1):

old version:
from flask_wtf import Form

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
from wtforms.form import Form
```